# How to get a table cell value from another site (same domain) using jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a very similar solution described under Q: How to get a table cell value using jquery? but in case where table is actually on another website within same domain (no server side scripting is available).

I will appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make an AJAX GET request to it (that is, if you're not impeded by the same origin policy), then you can use [jQuery's `.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

You essentially pass the function a resource and a selector, and it will fetch the resource and parse out the content of the selector and load it into whatever you called it on, then on complete execute a function that you also pass to it.  For example...

```
$('#emailAddress').load('index.html p.contactInfo span.emailAddress', function() {
    alert('loaded new email address');
});
```

What this will do is:

- Find an element in the current DOM with the `id` "emailAddress"
- Make an AJAX GET request to `index.html`
- In the response, find a `p` with the class "contactInfo" which contains a `span` with the class "emailAddress"
- Set the content of that `span` to the originally selected element (`id` "emailAddress")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load information from another page on your site, you want to use .load() via jquery.

$('#ValueContainerOnYourPage').load('SomeWebPage.html #SelectorForTheElementYouWant');

That will take an element on a page and load it into an element on your page. Once you have this information you can use the methods in that other post to get the specific data you want.

You can read more about load here: http://api.jquery.com/load/